# OpenVPN UDP TLS handshake blocked by provider - how to tunnel via SSH?

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a company OpenVPN over UDP, but I'm currently in a country that blocks VPN access. I can connect to the VPN, but after a minute or so, it fails with "TLS handshake failed" and is unable to reconnect.

I have actually contacted the local ISP and they claim they have investigated and that there should be no restrictions. They say it's an issue with the VPN setup, but I know that's not true because it's working fine in other countries. I have also tried tethering with my phone, same issue. So obviously the ISP/the government is blocking the VPN connection, but the ISP's tech support team is either lying about it or (more likely), they're simply incompetent.

Anyway, my webspace in a "free" country comes with SSH access (without root access though) and I have added a "dynamic port" in PuTTY and configured my OpenVPN client to use it as a SOCKS proxy. However, OpenVPN always says: "Socks proxy returned bad reply"

Is there some other way I can make this work **without making changes to the OpenVPN server**?
I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: SOCKS isn’t guaranteed to do UDP. SSH doesn’t do UDP.

Comment: @DanielB Is there some other tool I can use?